# When creating primary and foreign keys is the CONSTRAINT keyword optional?

Tags: constraint

When creating a new table, sometimes examples show the primary and foreign keys defined with the `CONSTRAINT` keyword and other times without the `CONSTRAINT` keyword. Is the only reason to use the `CONSTRAINT` keyword to give the constraint a name? Or are there other reasons that you would choose to use or not use this keyword?

Example 1 (without the keyword):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Example 2 (with the keyword):

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Age int,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Other than assigning a specified constraint name, do DBMSes see these two examples differently?  I'm thinking about SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, and PostgreSQL in particular.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For SQL Server, the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql) spell this out in excellent clarity (bold is my formatting):

> CONSTRAINT
>   Is an **optional** keyword that indicates the start of the definition of a PRIMARY KEY, NOT NULL, UNIQUE, FOREIGN KEY, or CHECK constraint.

Thus you do not need to specify `CONSTRAINT xxx` in your `CREATE TABLE` statement.

Note, however, that **if you don't specify the constraint name, SQL Server will generate one for you** if you include a constraint definition.  This example shows creating a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, without naming it.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ConstraintTest
(
    ConstraintTest_ID int NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
) ON [PRIMARY];

SELECT o_parent.name
    , o.name
FROM sys.key_constraints kc
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON kc.object_id = o.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o_parent on kc.parent_object_id = o_parent.object_id
WHERE o_parent.name = 'ConstraintTest';

DROP TABLE dbo.ConstraintTest
```

The results of the `SELECT` statement above:

```
+----------------+--------------------------------+
|      name      |              name              |
+----------------+--------------------------------+
| ConstraintTest | PK__Constrai__471ED41490593601 |
+----------------+--------------------------------+
```

This leads to the generally accepted best-practice of naming all constraints, as in:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ConstraintTest
(
    ConstraintTest_ID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_ConstraintTest
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

As always, the "It Depends™" moment here is for temporary tables; we almost never specify the name of a constraint applied to a temp table since we want them to be unique, and allowing SQL Server to name them ensures they are in fact unique.  If you *do* specify the constraint name, then only a single copy of that temp table can exist at any given time; attempting to create more than one copy of the temp table will result in an error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 19
>   There is already an object named 'PK_ConstraintTest' in the database.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 19
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

You can easily add a `UNIQUE` constraint to an existing column without a name; as in:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Blah
ADD UNIQUE (SomeColumn);
```

In the example you've added to your question, the only difference is you are not *specifying* a constraint name, thereby allowing SQL Server to generate a name for the constraint.  Other than the name of the constraint, there is no difference between the two tables.